# issues installing MariaDB-5.2 in ubuntu Maverick

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, apt, mariadb

I was not sure if this question is more appropiate maybe in server fault, although i've found other MariaDB questions related to installation on this site, so i'll assume it is ok

I followed these instructions:
    [installing-mariadb-deb-files](http://kb.askmonty.org/v/installing-mariadb-deb-files)

and i added the following to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list

```
deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu maverick main
```

and i did sudo apt-get install mariadb*

and i get this error (at the end):

```
$ sudo apt-get install mariadb*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libmariadbclient-dev' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadbclient16' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadbclient16-dev' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-common' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadbd-dev' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadbclient-dev' instead of 'libmariadbclient16-dev'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' instead of 'mariadb-common'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-5.2' instead of 'mariadb-server-core-5.1'
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmariadbclient-dev libmariadbclient16 libmariadbd-dev libmysqlclient16
  libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mariadb-client mariadb-client-5.2 mariadb-client-core-5.2 mariadb-server mariadb-server-5.2
  mariadb-server-core-5.2 mariadb-test mariadb-test-5.2 mysql-common zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmariadbclient-dev libmariadbclient16 libmariadbd-dev libnet-daemon-perl
  libplrpc-perl mariadb-client mariadb-client-5.2 mariadb-client-core-5.2 mariadb-server mariadb-server-5.2 mariadb-server-core-5.2
  mariadb-test mariadb-test-5.2 zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmysqlclient16 mysql-common
2 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 230 not upgraded.
Need to get 39.7MB of archives.
After this operation, 199MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Get:1 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main mysql-common all 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [10.6kB]
Get:2 http://pa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main libnet-daemon-perl all 0.43-1 [46.9kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main libmariadbclient16 i386 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [1,418kB]
Get:4 http://pa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main libplrpc-perl all 0.2020-2 [36.0kB]
Get:5 http://pa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main libdbi-perl i386 1.611-1 [825kB]
Get:6 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main libmysqlclient16 i386 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [4,308B]            
Get:7 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main mariadb-client-core-5.2 i386 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [83.1kB]     
Get:8 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main mariadb-client-5.2 i386 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [1,712kB]         
Get:9 http://pa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main libdbd-mysql-perl i386 4.016-1 [138kB]                                           
Get:10 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main mariadb-server-core-5.2 i386 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [4,125kB]   
Get:11 http://pa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main libhtml-template-perl all 2.9-1 [65.8kB]                                        
Get:12 http://pa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main zlib1g-dev i386 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu1 [188kB]                                 
Get:13 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main mariadb-server-5.2 i386 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [13.3MB]         
Get:14 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main libmariadbclient-dev i386 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [1,680kB]      
Get:15 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main libmariadbd-dev i386 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [6,205kB]           
Get:16 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main mariadb-client all 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [4,214B]              
Get:17 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main mariadb-server all 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [4,342B]              
Get:18 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main mariadb-test-5.2 all 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [9,852kB]           
Get:19 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main mariadb-test all 5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick [4,152B]                
Fetched 39.7MB in 2min 21s (280kB/s)                                                                                                      
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 132956 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql-common 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 (using .../mysql-common_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mysql-common ...
Selecting previously deselected package libnet-daemon-perl.
Unpacking libnet-daemon-perl (from .../libnet-daemon-perl_0.43-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libplrpc-perl.
Unpacking libplrpc-perl (from .../libplrpc-perl_0.2020-2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libdbi-perl.
Unpacking libdbi-perl (from .../libdbi-perl_1.611-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmariadbclient16.
Unpacking libmariadbclient16 (from .../libmariadbclient16_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadbclient16_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0', which is also in package libmysqlclient16 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to replace libmysqlclient16 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 (using .../libmysqlclient16_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmysqlclient16 ...
Selecting previously deselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (from .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.016-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mariadb-client-core-5.2.
Unpacking mariadb-client-core-5.2 (from .../mariadb-client-core-5.2_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mariadb-client-5.2.
Unpacking mariadb-client-5.2 (from .../mariadb-client-5.2_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mariadb-server-core-5.2.
Unpacking mariadb-server-core-5.2 (from .../mariadb-server-core-5.2_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadbclient16_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of the log is the important part:

Unpacking libmariadbclient16 (from .../libmariadbclient16_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadbclient16_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0', which is also in package libmysqlclient16 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to replace libmysqlclient16 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 (using .../libmysqlclient16_5.2.5-mariadb99~maverick_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmysqlclient16 ...

According to this, debian noticed a name conflict (both MariaDB and MySQL provides the same libmysqlclient library) which it resolved by replacing the MySQL package with the MariaDB package.

If that's the case then the installation worked, except for a warning you can ignore.